# GCC multiple definition of functions linker error

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

I am trying to create a makefile and was able to get all of the files to compile but it fails on the linker step. Every function in the project is getting an error where it says GCC multiple definition of 'Function Name' then claims that it was first defined in the exact same spot. For example...

```
project/src/provCreator.o: In function `ProcessArgs':
/home/kevin/project/src/provCreator.c:380: multiple definition of `ProcessArgs'
project/src/provCreator.o:/home/kevin/project/src/provCreator.c:380: first defined here
```

What are possible causes of this error and how can it be fixed?

Thank you for helping.

Comment: What about posting line 380 of provCreator.c? ;)

Comment: The makefile might be useful, too. It sounds like the object files are being referenced twice somehow. (?!)

Answer (score 2):

Your makefile has `project/src/provCreator.c` file listed twice. Possibly, with different relative paths.

From your description, it seems that all c files are listed twice (ctrl-c/ctrl-v error?)

Comment: and/or possibly one `.c` file includes another

Comment: @MattMcNabb: that would have manifested itself with a slightly different error message.

Answer (score 1):

Any linker throws a multiple definition error while functions with the same name compiled or same function compiled multiple times due to duplicate listings in makefile. After compilation, while linking linker will be in confusion which object definition it has to link hence it throws an error.

In your case, please check your makefile, probably you might have listed provCreator.c twice.